# Bootcamp brightness not working

Tags: macos, mac, bootcamp

I just recently install my Windows 8 in the bootcamp (version 5.0.5033).I try to adjust the brightness but still remain very bright and also adjust in the bootcamp control panel but also same. The brightness is so bright until my eye cannot open. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the bootcamp drivers ? If you don't go there : http://www.apple.com/fr/support/bootcamp/

Comment: I already install the bootcamp driver but it still the same

Comment: Are using rEFIt ? If you want you can adjust it manualy : http://www.surebeatswork.com/2009/06/29/change-screen-brightness-in-bootcamp/

Comment: I try adjust manually already but still the same

Comment: Maybe this : http://superuser.com/questions/497271/windows-8-installed-with-boot-camp-does-not-show-brightness-or-volume-indicators